# Rudin's PMA 10.38 theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Suppose   $E$   is  a  convex open set in $\Bbb R^{n}$, $f \in C^{1}$, $p$ is an integer, $1\leq p  \leq n$ and $(D_{j}f)(x)=0$ ($p<j \leq n ,x\in E$).

Then there exists an $F \in C^{1}$ such that $$ (D_{p}F)(x)=f(x), (D_{j}F)(x)=0$$ if $p<j\leq n ,x \in E$.

**Proof**: Write $x=(x',x_{p},x'')$, where $x'=(x_{1},\dots,x_{p-1})$, $x''=(x_{p+1},\dots ,x_{n})$. When $p=1$, $x'$ is absent and when $p=n$, $x''$ is absent. Let $V$ be the set of all ($x',x_{p}$) such that $(x',x_{p},x'') \in E$ for some $x''$. Being a projection of $E$, $V$ is convex open set in $\Bbb R^{p}$. Since $E$ is convex and $(D_{j}f)(x)=0$ for $p<j\leq n$,$f(x)$ does not depend on $x''$. Hence there's a function $\phi$ with domain $V$ s.t $f(x)=\phi(x',x_{p})$, for all $x\in E$.

If $p$=1, $V$ is a segment in $\Bbb R^{1}$. Pick $c \in V$ and define $$F(x)=\int_{c}^{x_{1}} \phi (t) dt$$ ( mark this integral by ($\star$)).

If $p$>1, let $U$ be the set of all $x'\in \Bbb R^{p-1}$ such that $(x,x_{p}) \in V$ for some $x_{p}$. Then $U$ is a convex open set in $\Bbb R^{p-1}$ and there' a function $\alpha \in C^{1}$ such that $(x,\alpha (x')) \in V$ for all $x' \in U$. Define $$F(x)=\int_{\alpha (x')}^{x_{p}} \phi (x',t) dt$$ (mark this integral by ($\oplus$)).

I don't understand why is it necessary for  $E$  to be convex.

I also don't understand how do ($\star$) and ($\oplus$) guarantees that $$ (D_{p}F)(x)=f(x), (D_{j}F)(x)=0$$, if $p<j\leq n ,x \in E$

Would be satisfied.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "$E$ convex": so that the line segments corresponding to integration intervals are inside the domain of $f$. "why a solution": This is just an extension of the fundamental theorem of calculus, a solution to $D_pF=f$ that is constructed via integration is indeed a solution. The advanced fact is that you can exchange integration in $p$ direction with differentiation in a different, independent direction.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't understand in this case why $(D_jf)(x)$ will be equal of $0$?

Comment: Because this is the assumption. $f$ is independent of (or constant in the directions of) $x_j$ for $j>p$. Similarly the construction of $F$ does not depend on $x_j$ for $j>p$, thus also $F$ is constant in these directions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Why do we need that the line segments corresponding to integration intervals be inside the domain of ?

Comment: Because the integrand is only defined inside its domain. Without integrand no integral.

Comment: @LutzLehmann why do we need line? you don't have a clear answer why do we need convexity

Comment: The proof construction chooses to integrate along lines $t\mapsto x+te_p$, convexity giving that the intersection of the line with $E$ is a single segment. Explorations of more curved situations are simpler if they can be reduced to this basis case via isomorphism. // You do not need full convexity, as everything variable only happens along dimension $p$, but it is a well-established property that gives what is needed.

Comment: @LutzLehmann that's my question. why should we integrate along lines?

Comment: Why not? It is the easiest case and translates directly to the scalar case. Other shapes would require the invocation of the chain rule.